# RxJava order of execution confusion

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this very simple RxJava example

```
List<Integer> arrayIntegers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

Observable.fromIterable(arrayIntegers).map(i -> {
    Log.d("RxJava", "map i = " + i);
    return i;
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer i) {
        Log.d("RxJava", "next i = " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.d("RxJava", "Completed");
    }
});
```

Which gives this result..

```
D/RxJava: map i = 1
D/RxJava: map i = 2
D/RxJava: map i = 3
D/RxJava: map i = 4
D/RxJava: map i = 5
D/RxJava: next i = 1
D/RxJava: next i = 2
D/RxJava: next i = 3
D/RxJava: next i = 4
D/RxJava: next i = 5
```

What I was expecting though is something more like this

```
D/RxJava: map i = 1
D/RxJava: next i = 1
D/RxJava: map i = 2
D/RxJava: next i = 2
D/RxJava: map i = 3
D/RxJava: next i = 3
D/RxJava: map i = 4
D/RxJava: next i = 4
D/RxJava: map i = 5
D/RxJava: next i = 5
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong which is causing my order to be incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Rx pipeline operates in two different threads.
The first thread (`Schedulers.newThread()`), does the `fromIterable` and `map`. The second calls `DisposableObserver`.

Between the two threads there's (an invisible) buffer inside the `observeOn()` operator. So what happens is that the first thread gets some cpu time, quickly does all of its work and puts the results in the `observeOn` buffer. This probably happens during a single spin of that thread on the CPU.

Then, the second thread is launched, it takes the items from the buffer and continues the processing by calling your `DisposableObserver`.

I think that what you're looking for here is using a single thread. Remove the `observeOn` operator, see if it does what you want it to do.

Edit: Just tried removing the `observeOn` operator and running it on my machine. Here's the result:

```
RxJava map i = 1
RxJava next i = 1
RxJava map i = 2
RxJava next i = 2
RxJava map i = 3
RxJava next i = 3
RxJava map i = 4
RxJava next i = 4
RxJava map i = 5
RxJava next i = 5
```

For future reference, it might be useful for debugging purposes to print the name of the thread that reaches the various Rx operators. You can get the name using `Thread.currentThread().getName()`.

Comment: That works but I run into a different problem that I want in the next stage of this.

In the onNext call I want to be able to output progress with a Toast which has to run on the UI thread, so if I remove the observeOn line the Toast call will run on a non UI thread and crash the app.

I guess I can post to the UI thread via a Handler but I was hoping for a cleaner way with RxJava

Comment: What if you `subscribeOn` using the UI thread? Would that freeze the UI for too long?

Comment: I just tried the handler approach and its not going to work
This will run in an adapter which touches views when refreshing the adapter in onComplete so this approach wont work.

There must be a way of doing this in RxJava

In ASyncTasks it was easy to publish progress to UI thread so i'm sure it must be possible in RxJava

Comment: It looks like this might be possible with something called Subjects, anyone have a simple example of how a subject can be used to solve my problem?

Comment: You should ask this in a separate question. I think that the original-of-execution question has been answered.

Comment: Well it would be good to get this answered in the context of the original question

Comment: That's not how stack overflow works. The questions and answers aren't just for you. They have to be self-contained so they will make sense to other readers. This isn't a help desk. Also, there's little chance of anyone seeing your second question here, let alone try to answer it in a comment. You're free to wait for that to happen though.

Comment: Good point, i accepted the answer as you did answer my original question and I posted something else with more emphasis on asking about subjects, thanks