# RxJava order of execution confusion, subject needed

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have this very simple RxJava example

```
List<Integer> arrayIntegers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

Observable.fromIterable(arrayIntegers).map(i -> {
    Log.d("RxJava", "map i = " + i);
    return i;
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer i) {
        Log.d("RxJava", "next i = " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.d("RxJava", "Completed");
    }
});
```

Which gives this result..

```
D/RxJava: map i = 1
D/RxJava: map i = 2
D/RxJava: map i = 3
D/RxJava: map i = 4
D/RxJava: map i = 5
D/RxJava: next i = 1
D/RxJava: next i = 2
D/RxJava: next i = 3
D/RxJava: next i = 4
D/RxJava: next i = 5
```

What I was expecting though is something more like this

```
D/RxJava: map i = 1
D/RxJava: next i = 1
D/RxJava: map i = 2
D/RxJava: next i = 2
D/RxJava: map i = 3
D/RxJava: next i = 3
D/RxJava: map i = 4
D/RxJava: next i = 4
D/RxJava: map i = 5
D/RxJava: next i = 5
```

I want to be able to later use Toasts in the onNext callback and refresh an adapter in onCompleted so I cant remove observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

I believe this problem can be resolved with Subjects, anyone have a simple example of how a subject can be used to solve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RxJava order of execution confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056511/rxjava-order-of-execution-confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I was expecting though is something more like this

I'll assume that by this sentence you mean the order in the output. You'll get that order whenever subscription run in the same thread as from the publisher, but since both publisher and subscriber are running in different thread they are no longer synchronized in terms of the output, i.e the publisher may outpace the subscriber or the converse and the order of printing will no longer be guaranteed. What you're guaranteed instead is that your subscription receive events in a serialized way.

Even in the first output block you'll seeing that mapping happens before any push of event downstream, but that's only an illusion caused by the amount of data you have on `arrayIntegers`, try adding more elements to the list and you'll see how the pattern of the output breaks.